# How to divide a big dataset into multiple small files in Hadoop in an efficient way

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a big data set consisting of files with 1M records each and I'd like to divide it into some files with 1000 records each in Hadoop. I'm investigating different scenarios for achieving this goal. One is to make the split size small so that each mapper takes only a few records (~1000 records) and then output them. This requires running many mappers which is not efficient. The other solution is to consider one reducer and send all the records to it and them do the split there. This is also counter-intuitive to mapreduce as all the job is done by only one node. What is the efficient alternative to split this data sets into small files?

Comment: HDFS automatically divides your files into 64MB block by default. Its not depends on the size of the file. Even you can configure the block size to 128MB or 256MB based on the size of the data. Hence, I didnt understand why you want to split the file manually.

Comment: I need to do some calculation on each record in the mapper class, that's the reason I should do the split manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NLineInputFormat to specify how many records should be given as input for mappers.

Set the property 'mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap' to multiples of 1000 so that reasonable number of mappers are spawned.In mapper, Use multiple outputs to write each 1000 records to separate file  using counter increment logic.

Sample code for using multiple outputs to split data into 1000 records (for Text files)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class DataSplitter {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

        private Text outputValue = new Text();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        private MultipleOutputs multipleOutputs;

        private int fileCounter = 1;

        private List<String> recordList = new ArrayList<String>();

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        @Override
        protected void setup(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs(context);

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();

            recordList.add(line);

            if (recordList.size() == 1000) {

                for (int i = 0; i < recordList.size(); i++) {

                    outputValue.set(recordList.get(i));

                    multipleOutputs.write("mos", NullWritable.get(), outputValue, "output-" + fileCounter);

                }

                fileCounter++;

                recordList.clear();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            multipleOutputs.close();

            if (!recordList.isEmpty()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < recordList.size(); i++) {

                    outputValue.set(recordList.get(i));

                    context.write(NullWritable.get(), outputValue);

                }
                recordList.clear();

            }
        }

    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

        private Text outputValue = new Text();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        private MultipleOutputs multipleOutputs;

        private int fileCounter = 1;

        private List<String> recordList = new ArrayList<String>();

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        @Override
        protected void setup(Reducer<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs(context);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            for (Text value : values) {

                String line = value.toString();

                recordList.add(line);

                if (recordList.size() == 1000) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < recordList.size(); i++) {

                        outputValue.set(recordList.get(i));

                        multipleOutputs.write("mos", NullWritable.get(), outputValue, "output-" + fileCounter);

                    }
                    fileCounter++;
                    recordList.clear();
                }

                if (!recordList.isEmpty()) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < recordList.size(); i++) {

                        outputValue.set(recordList.get(i));

                        context.write(NullWritable.get(), outputValue);

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Reducer<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.cleanup(context);
            multipleOutputs.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job = new Job(conf, "DataSplitter");
        job.setJarByClass(DataSplitter.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path(args[1]), true);

        MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "mos", TextOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) == true ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: A few questions: 1)The input file is actually an avro file. can I still use NLineInputFormat? 2) Doesn't this mechanisim have the same downside as making the split size small?  3)How can I have multiple outputs in a mapper?

Comment: It cannot be used with Avro files in my knowledge. You can use multiple outputs both in mapper and reducer. Instantiate MultipleOutputs object in setup method and use it to emit records in map method.You can specify key,value and output file name while emitting record.

Comment: So if I can have multiple output files in the mapper, I think I can reach my goal?! Am I not right?

Comment: Another approach is to use multiple outputs to output each 1000 records to separate file in mapper phase.The extra records which doesn't add to count of 1000 in mapper phase can be emitted to single reducer.Same multiple output logic can be applied in reducer as well.

Comment: That actually looks a promising solution, could you kindly provide me with more details (a sample code) to do that? I need the input to be an avro file and the output be a sequence file of form <Text,Text>

Comment: I have edited answer to include sample code for multiple output usage(With input and output in text format).You can modify the logic to suit your file formats and input.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't particularly care about which record goes where, then calculate the number of files you want beforehand,and put it into the configuration. Then you could have a random number generator in the mapper, which generates a random number between 0 and (numFiles -1). Take `num % numReducers` as a key for the mapper output, with numReducers being the number of reducers you want to have.

For the value, use a `MapWritable<IntWritable,RecordClass>`, replacing `RecordClass` with whatever is convenient to store the record itself. for the `IntWritable` put the original random number denoting which file it should go into. put the rest of the record into the `RecordClass` slot.

In the reducer, extract the random number from the map, and for write the record to a file based on that number (write to file FileName1 if number is 1, FileName2 if number is 2 etc.).

Comment: As a matter of fact what is important is the number of records within each output files, not the number of output files.

As the processing in the mapper, makes the size of the records large, it's preferable if I can avoid having a reducer and can do that job in only mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Split big file into multiple small files using spark.

**Below example splits input-file into 2 files:**

```
     scala> sc.textFile("/xyz-path/input-file",2).saveAsTextFile("/xyz-path/output-file")
```

2nd parameter in textFile is minPartitions and it uses default partitioner. You can also use customer partitioner for better partitioning strategy. Read  more about Custom partition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127329/how-to-define-custom-partitioner-for-spark-rdds-of-equally-sized-partition-where).