# hadoop command to split files on HDFS

Tags: file, hadoop, split, hdfs

I have a file on hdfs having size 11 gb. I want to split it into multiple files in 1 gb. 
How can I do that? My hadoop version is 2.7.3

Comment: Why you want to split the file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567139/how-to-divide-a-big-dataset-into-multiple-small-files-in-hadoop-in-an-efficient

Comment: `hdfs dfs -Ddfs.block.size=1G -put file`

Answer (score 0):

If you have spark, try below-

Below example splits input-file into 2 files:

`spark-shell`

```
scala> sc.textFile("/xyz-path/input-file",2).saveAsTextFile("/xyz-path/output-file")
```

Answer (score 0):

In HDFS, the file is already split, per `dfs.block.size` setting