# How to define partitioning of DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I've started using Spark SQL and DataFrames in Spark 1.4.0.  I'm wanting to define a custom partitioner on DataFrames, in Scala, but not seeing how to do this.

One of the data tables I'm working with contains a list of transactions, by account, silimar to the following example.

```
Account   Date       Type       Amount
1001    2014-04-01  Purchase    100.00
1001    2014-04-01  Purchase     50.00
1001    2014-04-05  Purchase     70.00
1001    2014-04-01  Payment    -150.00
1002    2014-04-01  Purchase     80.00
1002    2014-04-02  Purchase     22.00
1002    2014-04-04  Payment    -120.00
1002    2014-04-04  Purchase     60.00
1003    2014-04-02  Purchase    210.00
1003    2014-04-03  Purchase     15.00
```

At least initially, most of the calculations will occur between the transactions within an account.  So I would want to have the data partitioned so that all of the transactions for an account are in the same Spark partition.

But I'm not seeing a way to define this.  The DataFrame class has a method called 'repartition(Int)', where you can specify the number of partitions to create.  But I'm not seeing any method available to define a custom partitioner for a DataFrame, such as can be specified for an RDD.

The source data is stored in Parquet.  I did see that when writing a DataFrame to Parquet, you can specify a column to partition by, so presumably I could tell Parquet to  partition it's data by the 'Account' column.  But there could be millions of accounts, and if I'm understanding Parquet correctly, it would create a distinct directory for each Account, so that didn't sound like a reasonable solution.

Is there a way to get Spark to partition this DataFrame so that all data for an Account is in the same partition?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127329/how-to-define-custom-partitioner-for-spark-rdds-of-equally-sized-partition-where

Comment: If you can tell Parquet to partition by account, you can probably partition by `int(account/someInteger)` and thereby get a reasonable number of accounts per directory.

Comment: @ABC: I did see that link.  Was looking for the equivalent of that `partitionBy(Partitioner)` method, but for DataFrames instead of RDDs.

I do now see that `partitionBy` is only available for _Pair_ RDDs, not sure why that is.

Comment: @Paul:  I did consider doing what you describe. A few things held me back:

Comment: continuing....

(1) That is for "Parquet-partitioning".  I wasn't able to find any docs that state that Spark-partitioning will actually use Parquet-partitioning.
(2) If I understand the Parquet docs, I need to define a new field "foo", then each Parquet directory would have a name like "foo=123". But if I construct a query involving _AccountID_, how would Spark/hive/parquet know that there was any linkage between _foo_ and _AccountID_?

Comment: Hi rake! you wrote "The source data is stored in Parquet. I did see that when writing a DataFrame to Parquet, you can specify a column to partition by, so presumably I could tell Parquet to partition it's data by the 'Account' column." 
How can we get this functionality?

Comment: See my answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061350/spark-reading-data-from-mysql-in-parallel/39537064#39537064](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061350/spark-reading-data-from-mysql-in-parallel/39537064#39537064)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

### Spark >= 2.3.0

[SPARK-22614](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22614) exposes range partitioning.

```
val partitionedByRange = df.repartitionByRange(42, $"k")

partitionedByRange.explain
// == Parsed Logical Plan ==
// 'RepartitionByExpression ['k ASC NULLS FIRST], 42
// +- AnalysisBarrier Project [_1#2 AS k#5, _2#3 AS v#6]
// 
// == Analyzed Logical Plan ==
// k: string, v: int
// RepartitionByExpression [k#5 ASC NULLS FIRST], 42
// +- Project [_1#2 AS k#5, _2#3 AS v#6]
//    +- LocalRelation [_1#2, _2#3]
// 
// == Optimized Logical Plan ==
// RepartitionByExpression [k#5 ASC NULLS FIRST], 42
// +- LocalRelation [k#5, v#6]
// 
// == Physical Plan ==
// Exchange rangepartitioning(k#5 ASC NULLS FIRST, 42)
// +- LocalTableScan [k#5, v#6]
```

[SPARK-22389](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22389) exposes external format partitioning in the [Data Source API v2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15689).

### Spark >= 1.6.0

In Spark >= 1.6 it is possible to use partitioning by column for query and caching. See: [SPARK-11410](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11410) and [SPARK-4849](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4849) using `repartition` method:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("A", 3), ("C", 1)
).toDF("k", "v")

val partitioned = df.repartition($"k")
partitioned.explain

// scala> df.repartition($"k").explain(true)
// == Parsed Logical Plan ==
// 'RepartitionByExpression ['k], None
// +- Project [_1#5 AS k#7,_2#6 AS v#8]
//    +- LogicalRDD [_1#5,_2#6], MapPartitionsRDD[3] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:27
// 
// == Analyzed Logical Plan ==
// k: string, v: int
// RepartitionByExpression [k#7], None
// +- Project [_1#5 AS k#7,_2#6 AS v#8]
//    +- LogicalRDD [_1#5,_2#6], MapPartitionsRDD[3] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:27
// 
// == Optimized Logical Plan ==
// RepartitionByExpression [k#7], None
// +- Project [_1#5 AS k#7,_2#6 AS v#8]
//    +- LogicalRDD [_1#5,_2#6], MapPartitionsRDD[3] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:27
// 
// == Physical Plan ==
// TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(k#7,200), None
// +- Project [_1#5 AS k#7,_2#6 AS v#8]
//    +- Scan PhysicalRDD[_1#5,_2#6]
```

Unlike `RDDs` Spark `Dataset` (including `Dataset[Row]` a.k.a `DataFrame`) cannot use custom partitioner as for now. You can typically address that by creating an artificial partitioning column but it won't give you the same flexibility.

### Spark < 1.6.0:

One thing you can do is to pre-partition input data before you create a `DataFrame`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("x", StringType, false),
  StructField("y", LongType, false),
  StructField("z", DoubleType, false)
))

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Row("foo", 1L, 0.5), Row("bar", 0L, 0.0), Row("??", -1L, 2.0),
  Row("foo", -1L, 0.0), Row("??", 3L, 0.6), Row("bar", -3L, 0.99)
))

val partitioner = new HashPartitioner(5) 

val partitioned = rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0), r))
  .partitionBy(partitioner)
  .values

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(partitioned, schema)
```

Since `DataFrame` creation from an `RDD` requires only a simple map phase existing partition layout should be preserved*:

```
assert(df.rdd.partitions == partitioned.partitions)
```

The same way you can repartition existing `DataFrame`:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  df.rdd.map(r => (r.getInt(1), r)).partitionBy(partitioner).values,
  df.schema
)
```

So it looks like it is not impossible. The question remains if it make sense at all. I will argue that most of the time it doesn't:

1. Repartitioning is an expensive process. In a typical scenario most of the data has to be serialized, shuffled and deserialized. From the other hand number of operations which can benefit from a pre-partitioned data is relatively small and is further limited if internal API is not designed to leverage this property.

   - joins in some scenarios, but it would require an internal support,
   - window functions calls with matching partitioner. Same as above, limited to a single window definition. It is already partitioned internally though, so pre-partitioning may be redundant,
   - simple aggregations with `GROUP BY` - it is possible to reduce memory footprint of the temporary buffers**, but overall cost is much higher. More or less equivalent to `groupByKey.mapValues(_.reduce)` (current behavior) vs `reduceByKey` (pre-partitioning). Unlikely to be useful in practice.
   - data compression with `SqlContext.cacheTable`. Since it looks like it is using run length encoding, applying `OrderedRDDFunctions.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` could improve compression ratio.
2. Performance is highly dependent on a distribution of the keys. If it is skewed it will result in a suboptimal resource utilization. In the worst case scenario it will be impossible to finish the job at all.
3. A whole point of using a high level declarative API is to isolate yourself from a low level implementation details. As already mentioned by [@dwysakowicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4250114/dwysakowicz) and [@RomiKuntsman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073426/romi-kuntsman) an optimization is a job of the [Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html). It is a pretty sophisticated beast and I really doubt you can easily improve on that without diving much deeper into its internals.

### Related concepts

**Partitioning with JDBC sources**:

JDBC data sources support [`predicates` argument](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L194). It can be used as follows:

```
sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, table, Array("foo = 1", "foo = 3"), props)
```

It creates a single JDBC partition per predicate. Keep in mind that if sets created using individual predicates are not disjoint you'll see duplicates in the resulting table.

**`partitionBy` method in `DataFrameWriter`**:

Spark `DataFrameWriter` provides `partitionBy` method which can be used to "partition" data on write. It separates data on write using provided set of columns

```
val df = Seq(
  ("foo", 1.0), ("bar", 2.0), ("foo", 1.5), ("bar", 2.6)
).toDF("k", "v")

df.write.partitionBy("k").json("/tmp/foo.json")
```

This enables predicate push down on read for queries based on key:

```
val df1 = sqlContext.read.schema(df.schema).json("/tmp/foo.json")
df1.where($"k" === "bar")
```

but it is not equivalent to `DataFrame.repartition`. In particular aggregations like:

```
val cnts = df1.groupBy($"k").sum()
```

will still require `TungstenExchange`:

```
cnts.explain

// == Physical Plan ==
// TungstenAggregate(key=[k#90], functions=[(sum(v#91),mode=Final,isDistinct=false)], output=[k#90,sum(v)#93])
// +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(k#90,200), None
//    +- TungstenAggregate(key=[k#90], functions=[(sum(v#91),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[k#90,sum#99])
//       +- Scan JSONRelation[k#90,v#91] InputPaths: file:/tmp/foo.json
```

**`bucketBy` method in `DataFrameWriter`** (Spark >= 2.0):

`bucketBy` has similar applications as `partitionBy` but it is available only for tables (`saveAsTable`). Bucketing information can used to optimize joins:

```
// Temporarily disable broadcast joins
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)

df.write.bucketBy(42, "k").saveAsTable("df1")
val df2 = Seq(("A", -1.0), ("B", 2.0)).toDF("k", "v2")
df2.write.bucketBy(42, "k").saveAsTable("df2")

// == Physical Plan ==
// *Project [k#41, v#42, v2#47]
// +- *SortMergeJoin [k#41], [k#46], Inner
//    :- *Sort [k#41 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
//    :  +- *Project [k#41, v#42]
//    :     +- *Filter isnotnull(k#41)
//    :        +- *FileScan parquet default.df1[k#41,v#42] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/spark-warehouse/df1], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(k)], ReadSchema: struct<k:string,v:int>
//    +- *Sort [k#46 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
//       +- *Project [k#46, v2#47]
//          +- *Filter isnotnull(k#46)
//             +- *FileScan parquet default.df2[k#46,v2#47] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/spark-warehouse/df2], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(k)], ReadSchema: struct<k:string,v2:double>
```

---

* By *partition layout* I mean only a data distribution. `partitioned` RDD has no longer a partitioner.
** Assuming no early projection. If aggregation covers only small subset of columns there is probably no gain whatsoever.

Comment: @bychance Yes and no. Data layout will be preserved but AFAIK it won't give you benefits like partition pruning.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks, is there a way to check partition allocation of parquet file to validate df.save.write indeed save the layout? And if I do df.repartition("A"), then do df.write.repartitionBy("B"), the physical folder structure will be partitioned by B, and within each B value folder, will it still keep the partition by A?

Comment: @bychance `DataFrameWriter.partitionBy` is logically not the same as `DataFrame.repartition`. Former on doesn't shuffle, it simply separates  the output. Regarding the first question.- data is saved per partition and there is no shuffle. You can easily check that by reading individual files. But Spark alone has no way to know about it if this is what you really want.

Answer (score 11):

In Spark < 1.6 If you create a `HiveContext`, not the plain old `SqlContext` you can use the [HiveQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy#LanguageManualSortBy-SyntaxofClusterByandDistributeBy) `DISTRIBUTE BY colX...` (ensures each of N reducers gets non-overlapping ranges of x) & `CLUSTER BY colX...` (shortcut for Distribute By and Sort By) for example;

```
df.registerTempTable("partitionMe")
hiveCtx.sql("select * from partitionMe DISTRIBUTE BY accountId SORT BY accountId, date")
```

Not sure how this fits in with Spark DF api. These keywords aren't supported in the normal SqlContext (note you dont need to have a hive meta store to use the HiveContext)

*EDIT:* Spark 1.6+ now has this in the native DataFrame API

Comment: Are the partitions are preserved as the dataframe is saved?

Comment: how do you control how many partitions you can have in the hive ql example? e.g. in the pair RDD approach, you can do this to create 5 partitions: val partitioner = new HashPartitioner(5)

Comment: ok, found answer, it can be done like this: sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5")
I could not edit previous comment as i missed 5 mins limit

Answer (score 8):

So to start with some kind of answer : ) - You can't

I am not an expert, but as far as I understand DataFrames, they are not equal to rdd and DataFrame has no such thing as Partitioner.

Generally DataFrame's idea is to provide another level of abstraction that handles such problems itself. The queries on DataFrame are translated into logical plan that is further translated to operations on RDDs. The partitioning you suggested will probably be applied automatically or at least should be.

If you don't trust SparkSQL that it will provide some kind of optimal job, you can always transform DataFrame to RDD[Row] as suggested in of the comments.

Answer (score 7):

Use the DataFrame returned by:

```
yourDF.orderBy(account)
```

There is no explicit way to use `partitionBy` on a DataFrame, only on a PairRDD, but when you sort a DataFrame, it will use that in it's LogicalPlan and that will help when you need to make calculations on each Account.

I just stumbled upon the same exact issue, with a dataframe that I want to partition by account.
I assume that when you say "want to have the data partitioned so that all of the transactions for an account are in the same Spark partition", you want it for scale and performance, but your code doesn't depend on it (like using `mapPartitions()` etc), right?

Comment: What about if your code does depend on it because your are using mapPartitions?

Comment: You can convert the DataFrame to a RDD, and then Partition it (for example using aggregatByKey() and pass a custom Partitioner)

Answer (score 7):

I was able to do this using RDD. But I don't know if this is an acceptable solution for you.
Once you have the DF available as an RDD, you can apply [`repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions) to perform custom repartitioning of data.

Here is a sample I used:

```
class DatePartitioner(partitions: Int) extends Partitioner {

  override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
    val start_time: Long = key.asInstanceOf[Long]
    Objects.hash(Array(start_time)) % partitions
  }

  override def numPartitions: Int = partitions
}

myRDD
  .repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new DatePartitioner(24))
  .map { v => v._2 }
  .toDF()
  .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
```