# How to control the number of output part files created by Spark job upon writing?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am having couple of Spark jobs which processes thousands of files every day. File size may very from MBs to GBs. After finishing job I usually save using the following code

```
finalJavaRDD.saveAsParquetFile("/path/in/hdfs"); OR
dataFrame.write.format("orc").save("/path/in/hdfs") //storing as ORC file as of Spark 1.4
```

Spark job creates plenty of small part files in final output directory. As far as I understand Spark creates part file for each partition/task - is this correct? How do we control amount of part files Spark creates?

Finally, I would like to create Hive table using these parquet/orc directory and I heard Hive is slow when we have large no of small files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try using the [DataFrame.coalesce](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#coalesce(int)) method to decrease the number of partitions; it returns a DataFrame with the specified number of partitions (each of which becomes a file on insertion).

To increase or decrease the partitions you can use `Dataframe.repartition` function.
But `coalesce` does not cause shuffle while `repartition` does.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.6 you can use repartition on data frame, which means you'll get 1 file per hive partition. Beware of large shuffles though, best to have your DF partitioned properly from starts if possible.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32920122/2204206