# How to set the number of partitions/nodes when importing data into Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, database-partitioning, apache-spark-sql

**Problem:** I want to import data into Spark EMR from S3 using:

```
data = sqlContext.read.json("s3n://.....")
```

Is there a way I can set the number of nodes that Spark uses to *load* and *process* the data? This is an example of how I process the data:

```
data.registerTempTable("table")
SqlData = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
```

**Context**: The data is not too big, takes a long time to load into Spark and also to query from. I think Spark partitions the data into too many nodes. I want to be able to set that manually. I know when dealing with RDDs and `sc.parallelize` I can pass the number of partitions as an input. Also, I have seen `repartition()`, but I am not sure if it can solve my problem. The variable `data` is a `DataFrame` in my example.

Let me define partition more precisely. Definition one: commonly referred to as "partition key" , where a column is selected and indexed to speed up query (that is not what i want). Definition two: (this is where my concern is) suppose you have a data set, Spark decides it is going to distribute it across many nodes so it can run operations on the data in parallel. If the data size is too small, this may further slow down the process. How can i set that value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define partitioning of a Spark DataFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995699/how-to-define-partitioning-of-a-spark-dataframe)

Comment: Let me define partition more precisely. Definition one: commonly referred to as "partition key" , where a column is selected and indexed to speed up query. Definition two: (this is where my concern is) suppose you have a data set, Spark decides it is going to distribute it across many nodes so it can run operations on the data in parallel. If the data size is too small, this may further slow down the process. How can i set that value ?

Comment: You're correct in making a clear distinction between table partitioning as in relational databases vs. RDD partitioning. See [How to define partitioning of a Spark DataFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995699/how-to-define-partitioning-of-a-spark-dataframe), which describes how to do DataFrame partitioning, as in _RDD/distributed partitioning_.

Answer (score 14):

By default it partitions into 200 sets. You can change it by using set command in sql context `sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10");`. However you need to set it with caution based up on your data characteristics.

Comment: So how do you figure out what to set it too? What "data characteristics"?

Answer (score 11):

You can call `repartition()` on dataframe for setting partitions. You can even set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` this property after creating hive context or by passing to spark-submit jar:

```
spark-submit .... --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100
```

or

```
dataframe.repartition(100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Number of "input" partitions are fixed by the File System configuration.

1 file of 1Go, with a block size of 128M will give you 10 tasks. I am not sure you can change it.

repartition can be very bad, if you have lot of input partitions this will make lot of shuffle (data traffic) between partitions.

There is no magic method, you have to try, and use the webUI to see how many tasks are generated.