# spark reading data from mysql in parallel

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Im trying to read data from mysql and write it back to parquet file in s3 with specific partitions as follows:

```
df=sqlContext.read.format('jdbc')\
   .options(driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',url="""jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<>db?user=<usr>&password=<pass>""",
         dbtable='tbl',
         numPartitions=4 )\
   .load()


df2=df.withColumn('updated_date',to_date(df.updated_at))
df2.write.parquet(path='s3n://parquet_location',mode='append',partitionBy=['updated_date'])
```

My problem is that it open only one connection to mysql (instead of 4) and it doesn't write to parquert until it fetches all the data from mysql, because my table in mysql is huge (100M rows) the process failed on OutOfMemory.

Is there a way to configure Spark to open more than one connection to mysql and to write partial data to parquet?

Comment: https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/05_spark_sql_and_dataset_api.md#parallelizing-reads

Answer (score 6):

You should set these properties:

```
partitionColumn, 
lowerBound, 
upperBound, 
numPartitions
```

as it is documented here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

Answer (score 5):

For Spark >= 2.0
I've created a class with next methods:

```
...
private val dbUrl =
s"""jdbc:mysql://${host}:${port}/${db_name}
    |?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
    |&read_buffer_size=100M""".stripMargin.replace("\n", "")

def run(sqlQuery: String): DataFrame = {
println(sqlQuery)
Datapipeline.spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .option("url", dbUrl)
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", pass)
  .option("dbtable", s"($sqlQuery) as tmp")
  .load()
}
...
def getBounds(table: String, whereClause: String, partitionColumn: String): Array[Int] = {
val sql = s"select min($partitionColumn) as min, max($partitionColumn) as max from $table${
  if (whereClause.length > 0) s" where $whereClause"
}"
val df = run(sql).collect()(0)

Array(df.get(0).asInstanceOf[Int], df.get(1).asInstanceOf[Int])
}

def getTableFields(table: String): String = {
val sql =
  s"""
     |SELECT *
     |FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
     |WHERE table_name LIKE '$table'
     |  AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '${db_name}'
     |ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
   """.stripMargin
run(sql).collect().map(r => r.getAs[String]("COLUMN_NAME")).mkString(", ")
}

/**
* Returns DataFrame partitioned by <partritionColumn> to number of partitions provided in
* <numPartitions> for a <table> with WHERE clause
* @param table - a table name
* @param whereClause - WHERE clause without "WHERE" key word
* @param partitionColumn - column name used for partitioning, should be numeric
* @param numPartitions - number of partitions
* @return - a DataFrame
*/
def run(table: String, whereClause: String, partitionColumn: String, numPartitions: Int): DataFrame = {
val bounds = getBounds(table, whereClause, partitionColumn)

val fields = getTableFields(table)
val dfs: Array[DataFrame] = new Array[DataFrame](numPartitions)

val lowerBound = bounds(0)
val partitionRange: Int = ((bounds(1) - bounds(0)) / numPartitions)

for (i <- 0 to numPartitions - 2) {
  dfs(i) = run(
    s"""select $fields from $table
        | where $partitionColumn >= ${lowerBound + (partitionRange * i)} and $partitionColumn < ${lowerBound + (partitionRange * (i + 1))}${
      if (whereClause.length > 0)
        s" and $whereClause"
    }
     """.stripMargin.replace("\n", ""))
}

dfs(numPartitions - 1) = run(s"select $fields from $table where $partitionColumn >= ${lowerBound + (partitionRange * (numPartitions - 1))}${
  if (whereClause.length > 0)
    s" and $whereClause"
}".replace("\n", ""))

dfs.reduceLeft((res, df) => res.union(df))

}
```

Last `run` method will create a number of necessary partitions. When you call an action method Spark will create as many parallel tasks as many partitions have been defined for the DataFrame returned by the `run` method.

Enjoy.