# instead of fetching multiple tables using pyspark how can we execute join query using jdbc

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

customer - c_id, c_name, c_address
product - p_id, p_name, price
supplier - s_id, s_name, s_address
orders - o_id, c_id, p_id, quantity, time

```
SELECT o.o_id,
       c.c_id,
       c.c_name,
       p.p_id,
       p.p_name,
       p.price * o.quantity AS amount
FROM customer c
JOIN orders o ON o.c_id = c.c_id
JOIN product p ON p.p_id = o.p_id;
```

I want to execute above query without fetching 3 tables as individual data frames in pyspark and performing joins on dataframes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use query in-place of table as described below

Reference [PySpark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc)

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(
        "url", "(query) as table", 
        properties={"user":"username", "password":"password"})
```

In your case it will be:

```
df = spark.read.jdbc("url", """
    (
        SELECT o.o_id,
            c.c_id,
            c.c_name,
            p.p_id,
            p.p_name,
            p.price * o.quantity AS amount
            FROM customer c
            JOIN orders o ON o.c_id = c.c_id
            JOIN product p ON p.p_id = o.p_id
    ) as table""", properties={"user":"username", "password":"password"})
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537064) has used this type of query in place of table. Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43174838/4414721) is relevant in your case