# Spark JDBC connection to SQL Server times out often

Tags: r, sql-server, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm running Spark v2.2.1 via sparklyr v0.6.2 and pulling data from SQL Server via jdbc. I seem to be experiencing some network issue because *many times* (not every time) my executor doing a write to SQL Server fails with error:

```
Prelogin error: host <my server> port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection timed out (Read failed) ClientConnectionId:...
```

I am running my sparklyr session with the following configurations:

```
spark_conf = spark_config()
spark_conf$spark.executor.cores <- 8
spark_conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "8G"
spark_conf$`sparklyr.shell.executor-memory` <- "12G"
spark_conf$spark.serializer <- "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
spark_conf$spark.network.timeout <- 400
```

But interestingly the network timeout I've set above does not seem to apply based on the executor logs:

```
18/06/11 17:53:44 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_9_16 locally
18/06/11 17:53:45 WARN SQLServerConnection: ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: d3568a9f-049f-4772-83d4-ed65b907fc8b Prelogin error: host nciensql14.nciwin.local port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection timed out (Read failed) ClientConnectionId:d3568a9f-049f-4772-83d4-ed65b907fc8b
18/06/11 17:53:45 WARN SQLServerConnection: ConnectionID:2 ClientConnectionId: ecb084e6-99a8-49d1-9215-491324e8d133 Prelogin error: host nciensql14.nciwin.local port 1433 Error reading prelogin response: Connection timed out (Read failed) ClientConnectionId:ecb084e6-99a8-49d1-9215-491324e8d133
18/06/11 17:53:45 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 10.0 in stage 26.0 (TID 77)
```

Can someone help me understand what a prelogin error is and how to avoid this issue? Here is my write function:

```
function (df, tbl, db, server = NULL, user, pass, mode = "error", 
    options = list(), ...) 
{
    sparklyr::spark_write_jdbc(
  df, 
  tbl, 
  options = c(
    list(url = paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://", server, ".nciwin.local;", 
         "databaseName=", db, ";", 
         "user=", user, ";", 
         "password=", pass, ";"), 
       driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"), 
    options), 
  mode = mode, ...)
}
```

I've just updated my jdbc driver to version 6.0, but I don't think it made a difference. I hope i installed it correctly. I just dropped it into my `Spark/jars` folder and then added it into `Spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`.

**EDIT** 
I am reading in 23M rows in 24 partitions into Spark. My cluster has 4 nodes with 8 cores each and 18G memory. With my current configurations I have 4 executors with 8 cores each and 12G per executor. My function to read in the data looks as such:

```
function (sc, tbl, db, server = NULL, user, pass, repartition = 0, options = list(), ...) 
{
    sparklyr::spark_read_jdbc(
      sc, 
      tbl, 
      options = c(
        list(url = paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://", server, ".nciwin.local;"), 
             user = user, 
             password = pass, 
             databaseName = db, 
             dbtable = tbl, 
             driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"), 
        options), 
      repartition = repartition, ...)
}
```

I set `repartition` to 24 when running. As such, I'm not seeing the connection with the post suggested.

**EDIT 2**
I was able to fix my issue by getting rid of repartitioning. Can anyone explain why repartitioning with sparklyr is not effective in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve performance for slow Spark jobs using DataFrame and JDBC connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188295/how-to-improve-performance-for-slow-spark-jobs-using-dataframe-and-jdbc-connecti)

Comment: Hm, I'm not making the connection between these posts. My read is working well and I use 24 partitions, so I'm not seeing how that applies. Mind you, I used to do this fine with no read partitioning when I was connecting to a different SQL Server DB.

Comment: I'm not closing this question yet. The spark_read_jdbc function doesn't work the way you think it does. Repartitioning happens after the data is pulled , which is the source of the problem. You can check that in the [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/623852f0683a0a82bc46acca1e7c2438ce5ee7a6/R/data_interface.R#L609) of the function.

Comment: Which makes this question a duplicate. But if you wish to have a better understanding about how do you actually fix this, I advise you to read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027091/spark-2-1-hangs-while-reading-a-huge-datasets/45028675#45028675)

Comment: @eliasah if you answer the question with advice on why repartitioning caused timeout issues I will mark it as best answer to close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188295/how-to-improve-performance-for-slow-spark-jobs-using-dataframe-and-jdbc-connecti), as well as some other posts ([Whats meaning of partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41085238), [Converting mysql table to spark dataset is very slow compared to same from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696455), [Partitioning in spark while reading from RDBMS via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43150694), [spark reading data from mysql in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35061350)) and off-site resources ([Parallelizing Reads](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/05_spark_sql_and_dataset_api.md#parallelizing-reads)), by default Spark JDBC source reads all data sequentially into a single node.

There are two ways of parallelizing reads:

- Range splitting based on a numerical column with `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, `partitionColumn` and `numPartitions` `options` required, where `partitionColumn` is a stable numeric column ([pseudocolumns might not be a good choice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47619445))

  ```
  spark_read_jdbc(
    ...,
    options = list(
      ...
      lowerBound = "0",                 # Adjust to fit your data 
      upperBound = "5000",              # Adjust to fit your data 
      numPartitions = "42",             # Adjust to fit your data and resources
      partitionColumn = "some_numeric_column"
    )
   )
  ```
- `predicates` list - not supported in `sparklyr` at the moment.

Repartitioning (`sparklyr::sdf_repartition` doesn't resolve the problem because it happens after data has been loaded. Since shuffle (required for `repartition`) belongs to the most expensive operations in Spark it can easily crash the node.

As a result using:

- `repartition` parameter of `spark_read_jdbc`:
- `sdf_repartition`

is just a cargo cult practice, and most of the time does more harm than good. If data is small enough to be piped through a single node, then increasing number of partitions will usually decreases performance. Otherwise it will just crash.

That being said - if data is already processed by a single node it raises a question, if it makes sense to use Apache Spark at all. The answer will depend on the rest of your pipeline, but considering only component in question, it likely be negative.

Comment: What if I only have varchar column to work with? Am I completely out of luck?