# Best Approach for duplicate filtering in a Java Spark JavaPairRDD

Tags: apache-spark

I am learning spark and would like to seek best approaches for solving the below problem.

I have 2 datasets `users` and `transactions` as below and would like to join them to find unique locations per item sold.

The headers for the files are as below

```
id,email,language,location ----------- USER HEADERS
txid,productid,userid,price,desc -------------------- TRANSACTION HEADERS
```

Below is my approach

```
/*
         * Load user data set into userDataFrame
         * Load transaction data set into transactionDataFrame
         * join both on user id - userTransactionFrame
         * select productid and location columns from the joined dataset into a new dataframe - productIdLocationDataFrame
         * convert the new dataframe into a javardd - productIdLocationJavaRDD
         * make the javardd a pair rdd - productIdLocationJavaPairRDD
         * group the pair rdd by key - productLocationList
         * apply mapvalues on the grouped key to convert the list of values to a set of valued for duplicate filtering - productUniqLocations
         * 
         * */
```

I am not very sure that I have done this the right way and still feel "can be done better, differently".

I am doubtful of the part where I have done duplicate filtering from the JavaPairRDD.

Please evaluate the approach and code and let me know better solutions.

**Code**

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setAppName("Sample App - Uniq Location per item");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext("local[*]","A 1");
    //JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);

    //id    email   language    location ----------- USER HEADERS
    DataFrame userDataFrame = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("delimiter", "\t")
            .load("user");

    //txid  pid uid price   desc -------------------- TRANSACTION HEADERS
    DataFrame transactionDataFrame = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("delimiter", "\t")
            .load("transactions");

    Column joinColumn = userDataFrame.col("id").equalTo(transactionDataFrame.col("uid"));

    DataFrame userTransactionFrame = userDataFrame.join(transactionDataFrame,joinColumn,"rightouter");

    DataFrame productIdLocationDataFrame = userTransactionFrame.select(userTransactionFrame.col("pid"),userTransactionFrame.col("location"));

    JavaRDD<Row> productIdLocationJavaRDD = productIdLocationDataFrame.toJavaRDD();

    JavaPairRDD<String, String> productIdLocationJavaPairRDD = productIdLocationJavaRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, String, String>() {

        public Tuple2<String, String> call(Row inRow) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2(inRow.get(0),inRow.get(1));
        }
    });


    JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> productLocationList = productIdLocationJavaPairRDD.groupByKey();

    JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> productUniqLocations = productLocationList.mapValues(new Function<Iterable<String>, Iterable<String>>() {

        public Iterable<String> call(Iterable<String> inputValues) throws Exception {
            return new HashSet<String>((Collection<? extends String>) inputValues);
        }
    });

    productUniqLocations.saveAsTextFile("uniq");
```

The good part is that the code runs and generates the output that I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest hanging fruit is [getting rid](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) of `groupByKey`.

Using `aggregateByKey` should do the job since the output type of the value is different (we want a set per key).

Code in Scala :

```
 pairRDD.aggregateByKey(new java.util.HashSet[String])
((locationSet, location) => {locationSet.add(location); locationSet},
 (locSet1, locSet2) => {locSet1.addAll(locSet2); locSet1}
)
```

Java Equivalent:

```
Function2<HashSet<String>, String, HashSet<String>> sequenceFunction = new Function2<HashSet<String>, String, HashSet<String>>() {

            public HashSet<String> call(HashSet<String> aSet, String arg1) throws Exception {
                aSet.add(arg1);
                return aSet;
            }
        };

        Function2<HashSet<String>, HashSet<String>, HashSet<String>> combineFunc = new Function2<HashSet<String>, HashSet<String>, HashSet<String>>() {

            public HashSet<String> call(HashSet<String> arg0, HashSet<String> arg1) throws Exception {
                arg0.addAll(arg1);
                return arg0;
            }
        };

        JavaPairRDD<String, HashSet<String>> byKey = productIdLocationJavaPairRDD.aggregateByKey(new HashSet<String>(), sequenceFunction, combineFunc );
```

---

Secondly, joins work the best when the datasets are co-partitioned.

Since you are dealing with dataframes, partitioning out of box is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995699/how-to-define-partitioning-of-a-spark-dataframe) if you are using Spark < 1.6. Thus, you may want to read data into RDDs, partition them and then create dataframes. For your use case, it might be better to not involve dataframes at all.