# Does Spark know the partitioning key of a DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, window-functions

I want to know if Spark knows the partitioning key of the parquet file and uses this information to avoid shuffles.

**Context:**

Running Spark 2.0.1 running local SparkSession. I have a csv dataset that I am saving as parquet file on my disk like so:

```
val df0 = spark
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("delimiter", ";")
  .option("inferSchema", false)
  .load("SomeFile.csv"))


val df = df0.repartition(partitionExprs = col("numerocarte"), numPartitions = 42)

df.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .format("parquet")
  .option("inferSchema", false)
  .save("SomeFile.parquet")
```

I am creating 42 partitions by column `numerocarte`. This should group multiple `numerocarte` to same partition. I don't want to do partitionBy("numerocarte") at the `write` time because I don't want one partition per card. It would be millions of them.

After that in another script I read this `SomeFile.parquet` parquet file and do some operations on it. In particular I am running a `window function` on it where the partitioning is done on the same column that the parquet file was repartitioned by.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df2 = spark.read
  .format("parquet")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("inferSchema", false)
  .load("SomeFile.parquet")

val w = Window.partitionBy(col("numerocarte"))
.orderBy(col("SomeColumn"))

df2.withColumn("NewColumnName",
      sum(col("dollars").over(w))
```

After `read` I can see that the `repartition` worked as expected and DataFrame `df2` has 42 partitions and in each of them are different cards.

**Questions:**

1. Does Spark know that the dataframe `df2` is partitioned by column `numerocarte`?
2. If it knows, then there will be no shuffle in the window function. True?
3. If it does not know, It will do a shuffle in the window function. True?
4. If it does not know, how do I tell Spark the data is already partitioned by the right column?
5. How can I check a partitioning key of `DataFrame`? Is there a command for this? I know how to check number of partitions but how to see partitioning key?
6. When I print number of partitions in a file after each step, I have 42 partitions after `read` and 200 partitions after `withColumn` which suggests that Spark repartitioned my `DataFrame`.
7. If I have two different tables repartitioned with the same column, would the join use that information?

Comment: To check what partitioner dataframe has you should peek into underlying RDD.  `df.rdd.partitioner`. If two dfs have same partitioners, there there may be no shuffle. You can check if there will be shuffle by calling `df.explain`. To check number of partitions call `df.rdd.partitions.length`. To more complete explanation about partitioning see https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-partitions.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does Spark know that the dataframe df2 is partitioned by column numerocarte?

It does not.

> If it does not know, how do I tell Spark the data is already partitioned by the right column?

You don't. Just because you save data which has been shuffled, it does not mean, that it will be loaded with the same splits.

> How can I check a partitioning key of DataFrame?

There is no partitioning key once you loaded data, but you can check `queryExecution` for `Partitioner`.

---

In practice:

- If you want to support efficient pushdowns on the key, use `partitionBy` method of `DataFrameWriter`.
- If you want a limited support for join optimizations use `bucketBy` with metastore and persistent tables.

See [How to define partitioning of DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995699/how-to-define-partitioning-of-dataframe) for detailed examples.

Comment: Saving in Spark Warehouse also saved Metadata in Metastore like partitioning, order, etc :) But it's only a small addition

Comment: @T.Gawęda But there is no metadata from the previous actions, is it? Note that OP uses `repartition`.

Comment: I must check, but `repartition` should explicity add partitioning info. Nevertheless, it was more "common" addition, not connected very much with question ;) Just to precise. Already upvoted :)

Comment: Just to make sure I understood the answer of user8371915 correctly, based on your answer and the cited article, if I can't use partitionBy at write time, because it would create millions of partitions, there is nothing to be done. Data will be loaded with unspecified partitioning and window function will deal with repartitioning internally. True?

Comment: Ok thanks. Just one more related question: If I had two window functions chained like so `df.withColumn("x", sum(col("y")).over(w1)).withColumn("z", sum(col("t")).over(w2))` where w1 and w2 are over the same partitionBy column but maybe different rangeBetween, will spark at w2 know the data was already partitioned at w1? or it will repartition each time for w1 and w2?

Comment: You have to check execution plan. `rangeBetween`/`rowsBetween` should be a problem, different `orderBy`, might be.

Comment: From execution plan it seems that in cases where partitionBy column is the same, and orderBy column is the same, two window functions with different rangeBetween/rowsBetween do only one repartitioning.

Comment: This post and the answers form the best post I have read here on Spark.

Answer (score 18):

I am answering my own question for future reference what worked.

Following suggestion of @user8371915, bucketBy works!

I am saving my DataFrame `df`:

```
df.write
  .bucketBy(250, "userid")
  .saveAsTable("myNewTable")
```

Then when I need to load this table:

```
val df2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM myNewTable")

val w = Window.partitionBy("userid")

val df3 = df2.withColumn("newColumnName", sum(col("someColumn")).over(w)
df3.explain
```

**I confirm** that when I do window functions on `df2` partitioned by `userid` there is no shuffle! Thanks @user8371915!

**Some things I learned while investigating it**

- myNewTable looks like a normal parquet file but it is not. You could read it normally with `spark.read.format("parquet").load("path/to/myNewTable")` but the `DataFrame` created this way will not keep the original partitioning! You must use `spark.sql` `select` to get correctly partitioned `DataFrame`.
- You can look inside the table with `spark.sql("describe formatted myNewTable").collect.foreach(println)`. This will tell you what columns were used for bucketing and how many buckets there are.
- Window functions and joins that take advantage of partitioning often require also sort. You can sort data in your buckets at the write time using `.sortBy()` and the sort will be also preserved in the hive table. `df.write.bucketBy(250, "userid").sortBy("somColumnName").saveAsTable("myNewTable")`
- When working in local mode the table `myNewTable` is saved to a `spark-warehouse` folder in my local Scala SBT project. When saving in cluster mode with mesos via `spark-submit`, it is saved to hive warehouse. For me it was located in `/user/hive/warehouse`.
- When doing `spark-submit` you need to add to your `SparkSession` two options: `.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://addres-to-your-master:9083")` and `.enableHiveSupport()`. Otherwise the hive tables you created will not be visible.
- If you want to save your table to specific database, do `spark.sql("USE your database")` before bucketing.

**Update 05-02-2018**

I encountered some problems with spark bucketing and creation of Hive tables. Please refer to question, replies and comments in [Why is Spark saveAsTable with bucketBy creating thousands of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585744/why-is-spark-saveastable-with-bucketby-creating-thousands-of-files)

Comment: Excellent post. I am understanding this but I am wondering what optimization gets done if using nested correlated sub queries.