# Why after creating 5 partitions and 10 buckets, number of data files created at the backend is so high?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-partitioning, data-partitioning

Below is my code:

```
spark.range(1,10000).withColumn("hashId",col("id")%5).write.partitionBy("hashId").bucketBy(10,"id").saveAsTable("learning.test_table")
```

Spark Configuration:

```
./spark-shell --master yarn --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 5
```

**There are 5 partitions and inside each partition, there are 61 files:**

```
hdfs dfs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/learning.db/test_table/hashId=0 | wc -l
61
```

After creating this table when I checked the backend, it created 305 files + 1 _SUCCESS file.

Could someone please explain why it is creating 305 files?

Comment: 5 partitions * 61 files/partition = 305 files in total...?

Comment: or are you asking why there are 61 files / partition, rather than 10

Comment: yes why 61 files in each partition and also I want to understand how the spark configurations are impacting the number of files generated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Spark saveAsTable with bucketBy creating thousands of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585744/why-is-spark-saveastable-with-bucketby-creating-thousands-of-files)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I got an idea of how we can prevent these number of files, but can anybody explain to me the calculations behind getting 305 files.