# How to spark partitionBy/bucketBy correctly?

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, partition-by

Q1. Will adhoc (dynamic) repartition of the data a line before a join help to avoid shuffling or will the shuffling happen anyway at the repartition and there is no way to escape it?

Q2. should I repartition/partitionBy/bucketBy? what is the right approach if I will join according to column day and user_id in the future? (I am saving the results as hive tables with .write.saveAsTable). I guess to partition by day and bucket by user_id but that seems to create thousands of files (see [Why is Spark saveAsTable with bucketBy creating thousands of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585744/why-is-spark-saveastable-with-bucketby-creating-thousands-of-files))

Comment: @Hanan_Shteingart For Q1 there is no guarantee that doing repartition before join would eliminate shuffle .It would definitely shuffle the data unless there is small dataframe that can be broadcasted.

Answer (score 0):

Some 'guidance' off the top of my head, noting that title and body of text differ to a degree:

> Question 1:
>
> - A `JOIN` will do any (hash) partitioning / repartitioning required automatically - if needed and if not using a Broadcast JOIN. You may
>   set the number of partitions for shuffling or use the default - 200.
>   There are more parties (DF's) to consider.
> - repartition is a transformation, so any up-front repartition may not be executed at all due to Catalyst optimization - see the `physical plan` generated from the `.explain`. That's the deal with lazy
>   evaluation - determining if something is necessary upon Action
>   invocation.

> Question 2:
>
> - If you have a use case to `JOIN` certain input / output *regularly*, then using Spark's `bucketBy` is a good approach. It obviates shuffling. The
>   databricks docs show this clearly.
> - A Spark schema using `bucketBy` is *NOT compatible* with `Hive`. so these remain Spark only tables, unless this changed recently.
> - Using Hive partitioning as you state depend on push-down logic, partition pruning etc. It should work as well but you may have have
>   different number of partitions inside Spark framework after the read.
>   It's a bit more complicated than saying I have N partitions so I will
>   get N partitions on the initial read.