# Spark schema using bucketBy is NOT compatible with Hive

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am using Spark version 2.3 to write and save dataframes using `bucketBy`.

The table gets created in Hive but not with the correct schema. I am not able to select any data from the Hive table.

```
(DF.write
   .format('orc')
   .bucketBy(20, 'col1')
   .sortBy("col2")
   .mode("overwrite")
   .saveAsTable('EMP.bucketed_table1'))
```

I am getting below message:

> Persisting bucketed data source table `emp`.`bucketed_table1` into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format, which is NOT compatible with Hive.

The Hive Schema is being created as shown below:

```
hive> desc EMP.bucketed_table1;
OK
col                     array<string>           from deserializer
```

How to save and write dataframes to a Hive table that can be viewed later?

Comment: Try to create bucketed table in Hive, then insert into it from Spark instead of `saveAsTable`

Comment: Please link this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799025/error-using-spark-save-does-not-support-bucketing-right-now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All other DF Writer methods allow subsequent selecting from those bucketed tables via Hive and Impala editors, except they are not Spark bucketed.

You need to select from bucketed via spark.read. ...

This should help: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

The answer to your question is that it not currently possible to select via Hive or Impala from Spark bucketed tables.

Comment: If we are creating our dataframe using hive tables in pyspark, how can we create bucketed tables though pyspark, which can be viewed later in hive?

Comment: Well, my understanding is you cannot. But may be I am wrong. You can use spark.read for Spark, but from Hive or IMPALA editor - I took the message incompatible to mean exactly that and did not find a way to view.  May be there is but the message is pretty explicit. May be a custom (de) serializer ...

Comment: The only other option, imhu(nderstandjng), is to df.write.partitionBy to an already created Hive table with dynamic partition enabled. But that is a different approach.

Comment: Yes, we can use spark.read(path location of file) or using sql context to get the data back in pyspark. Is there anyway to look the bucketed tables in hive, which are being created by pyspark using bucketBy option.

Comment: I believe the question has been answered, as in currently not possible.

Comment: There is a post in stackoverflow that bucketBy tables can be viewed later in hive. If we set the below properties.  When doing spark-submit you need to add to your SparkSession two options: .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://addres-to-your-master:9083") and .enableHiveSupport(). Otherwise the hive tables you created will not be visible. Here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459208/does-spark-know-the-partitioning-key-of-a-dataframe.    Does anyone know if it works??

Comment: That’s interesting. I did not find that in latest dics. Will try later and if so withdraw answer.

Comment: I am wondering if we ard talkjng at cross purposes. I can resd bucketed tables via Spark no sweat. From Hive shell or Impala I cannot

Comment: Yes, i was also able to read it back in spark but was not able to view it in hive.. since schema was compatible..

Comment: so this is a neutral conversation

Answer (score 2):

While Spark (in versions <= 2.4, at least) doesn't directly support Hive's bucketing format, as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide-hive-compatibility.html#unsupported-hive-functionality) and [here](https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/hive-bucketing-in-apache-spark-with-tejas-patil), it is possible to get Spark to output bucketed data that is readable by Hive, by using SparkSQL to load the data into Hive; following your example it would be something like:

```
//enable Hive support when creating/configuring the spark session
val spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

//register DF as view that can be used with SparkSQL
DF.createOrReplaceTempView("bucketed_df")

//create Hive table, can also be done manually on Hive
val createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE bucketed_table1 (col1 int, col2 string) CLUSTERED BY col1 INTO 20 BUCKETS STORED AS PARQUET"
spark.sql(createTableSQL)

//load data from DF into Hive, output parquet files will be bucketed and readable by Hive
spark.sql("INSERT INTO bucketed_table1 SELECT * FROM bucketed_df")
```