# Error using spark 'save' does not support bucketing right now

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning, parquet

I have a `DataFrame` which I am trying to `partitionBy` a column, sort it by that column and save in parquet format using the following command:

```scala
df.write().format("parquet")
  .partitionBy("dynamic_col")
  .sortBy("dynamic_col")
  .save("test.parquet")
```

I get the following error:

```
reason: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'save' does not support bucketing right now;
```

Is `save(...)` not allowed?
Is only `saveAsTable(...)` allowed which saves the data to Hive?

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that `sortBy` is currently (Spark 2.3.1) supported only together with bucketing and bucketing needs to be used in combination with `saveAsTable` and also the bucket sorting column should not be part of partition columns.

So you have two options:

1. Do not use `sortBy`:

```scala
df.write
  .format("parquet")
  .partitionBy("dynamic_col")
  .option("path", output_path)
  .save()
```

2. Use `sortBy` with bucketing and save it through the metastore using `saveAsTable`:

```scala
df.write
  .format("parquet")
  .partitionBy("dynamic_col")
  .bucketBy(n, bucket_col)
  .sortBy(bucket_col)
  .option("path", output_path)
  .saveAsTable(table_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```scala
df.repartition("dynamic_col")
  .write
  .partitionBy("dynamic_col")
  .parquet("test.parquet")
```

Comment: Thank you! The job is running with the above correction.

Comment: Cool, no problem

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.