# Why is it not possible to determine the partitions in a dataframe if it is possible to get the count of partitions in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Using `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`, we can get the count of partitions. But how do we get the partitions?

I also tried to pick something up from the documentation and all the attributes (using `dir(df)`) of a dataframe. However, I could not find any API that would give the partitions, only `repartitioning`, `coalesce`, `getNumPartitions` were all that I could find.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48460070/10834788) and deduced that Spark does not know the partitioning key(s). My doubt is, if it does not know the partitioning key(s), and hence, does not know the partitions, how can it know their count? If it can, how to determine the partitions?

Comment: What do you mean by determining the partitions? Content, method? Partition number?

Comment: I am sorry for not being able to provide you the exact answer.

By 'partition', I mean the folders in which the data gets partitioned. For eg, created_month * 12 folders, each folder containing created_day * 30(almost) folders, and then files being stored in each of such `day` folder. Does it make sense?

Comment: No, as a dataframe is in memory and may be evicted to disk, but it sounds like yo mean when dataframe written to disk. That is data at rest and indeed different.

Comment: I am confused about the data you read and the outcome you expect. Can you clarify a bit? You can get the partitions using the partitions() method, as in: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#partitions--

Comment: @jpg
When I typed `df.rdd.partitions`, I got: `AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'partitions'`

Answer (score 2):

How about checking what the partition contains using `mapPartitionsWithIndex`

This code will work for some small dataset

```
def f(splitIndex, elements): 
  elements_text = ",".join(list(elements))
  yield splitIndex, elements_text

rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(f).take(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

pyspark provides the **[`spark_partition_id()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=ntile#pyspark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id)** function.

> **spark_partition_id()**
>
> A column for partition ID.
>
> Note: This is indeterministic because it depends on data partitioning
>   and task scheduling.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> spark.range(1,1000000)
      .withColumn("spark_partition",spark_partition_id())
      .groupby("spark_partition")
      .count().show(truncate=False)
+---------------+------+
|spark_partition|count |
+---------------+------+
|1              |500000|
|0              |499999|
+---------------+------+
```

Partitions are numbered from zero to `n-1` where `n` is the number you get from `getNumPartitions()`.

Is that what you're after? Or did you actually mean **Hive** partitions?