# Unexpected Shuffle while Calculating Mean by Partition from Hive Data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**My Question**: Why does Spark calculate `sum` and `count` from each partition, do an unnecessary (IMHO) shuffle (`Exchange hashpartitioning`), and then calculate the mean in `HashAggregate`?

**What could've been done**: Calculate the mean for each partition and then combine (union) the results.

**Details:**

I am reading data from Hive table defined below, which is partitioned by date.

```
spark.sql("""Create External Table If Not Exists daily_temp.daily_temp_2014 
(
 state_name string,
 ... 
) Partitioned By (
 date_local string
)
Location "./daily_temp/" 
Stored As ORC""")
```

It consists of daily measurement of temperature for various points in the US downloaded from [EPA Website](https://aqs.epa.gov/aqsweb/airdata/daily_TEMP_2017.zip).

Using the code below, data is loaded from Hive table into PySpark DataFrame:

```
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("Hive Partition Test")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
    .getOrCreate()
)

my_df = spark.sql("select * from daily_temp.daily_temp_2014")
```

I would like to calculate daily mean temperature per state.

```
daily_state_mean = (
   my_df
   .groupBy(
       my_df.date_local,
       my_df.state_name
   )
   .agg({"arithmetic_mean":"mean"})
)
```

And this is part of the physical (execution) plan:

```
+- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[date_local#3003, state_name#2998], functions=[avg(cast(arithmetic_mean#2990 as double))], output=[date_local#3003, state_name#2998, avg(CAST(arithmetic_mean AS DOUBLE))#3014])
  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(date_local#3003, state_name#2998, 365)
     +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[date_local#3003, state_name#2998], functions=[partial_avg(cast(arithmetic_mean#2990 as double))], output=[date_local#3003, state_name#2998, sum#3021, count#3022L])
        +- HiveTableScan [arithmetic_mean#2990, state_name#2998, date_local#3003], HiveTableRelation `daily_temp`.`daily_temp_2014`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [...], [date_local#3003]
```

Your advice and insights are highly appreciated.

Comment: The original hive table is partitioned only by `state_name` whereas groupBy also includes `state_name`. So, shuffle seems necessary. If original partition included `state_name`, i think plan may have been different.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing unexpected here. Spark SQL doesn't preserve partitioning information of the external source (yet).

If you want to optimize shuffles, you have `CLUSTER BY` / `bucketBy` your data. If you do, partition information will be used to optimize shuffles.

Reference  [How to define partitioning of DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30995699)

Comment: I couldn't find a `bucketBy` method. Adding `Cluster By` to my initial load SQL caused an even more expensive shuffle of all the data fields.

Comment: @pbahr For bucket by you'll need Spark 2.3 (but patch is trivially simple https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17077/files).

Comment: I did finally find `bucketBy` in the new version's documentation, but it is a write-time solution. My data is already written properly in Hive. I was looking for something with the same effect on the in-memory DF.