# How to force a certain partitioning in a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

EDIT 2022/02/18: I returned to this problem after a few years, and I believe my new solution below is substantially more performant than the current highest-voted solution.

Suppose I have a DataFrame with a column `partition_id`:

```
n_partitions = 2

df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    [1, 'A'],
    [1, 'B'],
    [2, 'A'],
    [2, 'C']
]).toDF(('partition_id', 'val'))
```

How can I repartition the DataFrame to guarantee that each value of `partition_id` goes to a separate partition, and that there are exactly as many actual partitions as there are distinct values of `partition_id`?

If I do a hash partition, i.e. `df.repartition(n_partitions, 'partition_id')`, that guarantees the right number of partitions, but some partitions may be empty and others may contain multiple values of `partition_id` due to hash collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous accepted solution which requires converting from a DataFrame to an RDD and back works, but is quite slow due to the repartitioning required.

The solution given below is much more performant -- the additional Spark operations are quite fast and thus overall it doesn't require any more compute/shuffle than a naive repartition.

At a high level, we use an iterative algorithm to invert Spark's partition hashing, then use this inverted map to create new partition keys which (when partitioned upon) give the expected distribution of partitions.

```
import itertools

from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def construct_reverse_hash_map(spark, n_partitions, fact = 10):
    """
    Given a target number of partitions, this function constructs a
    mapping from each integer partition ID (0 through N-1) to an
    arbitrary integer, which Spark will hash to that partition ID.

    By using these new (seemingly arbitrary) integers as a column
    to repartition on, one can guarantee a 1-to-1 mapping of
    partition levels to the final partitions.

    Example return value, for n_partitions=10:

    {
        5: 80,
        9: 90,
        8: 94,
        7: 99,
        0: 92,
        1: 98,
        6: 87,
        2: 91,
        3: 85,
        4: 93
    }

    If one had a column in a dataframe with 10 unique values, 80, 90, 94,
    etc, and then partitioned on this column into 10 partitions, then
    every row with value 80 would go into partition 5, every row with
    value 90 would go into partition 9, and so on.

    :param spark: SparkSession object
    :param n_partitions: desired number of unique partitions
    :param fact: initial search space of IDs will be n_partitions*fact
    :return: dictionary mapping from sequential partition IDs to hashed
             partition IDs.
    """

    max_retries = 10
    for i in range(max_retries):
        bigger_factor = fact * 2 ** i
        hashes = (
            spark.createDataFrame([Row(orig_id=i) for i in list(range(n_partitions * bigger_factor))])
            .withColumn("h", F.hash("orig_id") % n_partitions)
            .select("orig_id", F.when(F.col("h") >= 0, F.col("h")).otherwise(F.col("h") + n_partitions).alias("new_id"))
        )
        n_unique_ids = hashes.groupBy("new_id").count().count()

        if n_unique_ids == n_partitions:
            # find a mapping between the hashed values and the original partition IDs
            return {row["new_id"]: row["orig_id"] for row in hashes.collect()}
    raise Exception("Spark reverse hash algorithm failed to converge")

def add_deterministic_1to1_partitioner(df, original_part_col, new_part_col, part_levels, seed=42):
    """
    Returns a DataFrame with a new column which can be repartitioned on to give exactly the desired partitions. We determine what
    values this column will have by inverting Spark's hash.

    :param df: original DataFrame
    :param original_part_col: logical column to be repartitioned on
    :param new_part_col: new column to be actually repartitioned on
    :param part_levels: list of unique values of part_col
    :param seed: seed value for quasirandom assignment to partitions
    :return: original DataFrame plus new column for repartitioning
    """

    part_level_map = {part_level: i for i, part_level in enumerate(part_levels)}
    part_level_map_expr = F.create_map(*[F.lit(x) for x in itertools.chain(*list(part_level_map.items()))])

    hash_map = construct_reverse_hash_map(df.sql_ctx.sparkSession, len(part_level_map))
    hash_map_expr = F.create_map(*[F.lit(x) for x in itertools.chain(*list(hash_map.items()))])

    return (
        # convert partition level to sequential numeric partition ID
        df.withColumn("__part_id__", part_level_map_expr[F.col(original_part_col)].astype("bigint"))
        # add col which will result in 1-to-1 partitioning when repartitioend on
        .withColumn(new_part_col, hash_map_expr[F.col("__part_id__")].astype("bigint"))
        .drop("__part_id__")
    )
```

Demonstrating the functionality:

```
# construct example DataFrame
data = [
    [1, 'A0'],
    [1, 'A1'],
    [2, 'B0'],
    [2, 'B1'],
    [3, 'C0'],
    [3, 'C1'],
]
partition_levels = list(set([pid for pid, _ in data]))
n_partitions = len(partition_levels)

df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(('partition_id', 'val'))
```

A naive repartitioning on the desired partition column results in collisions -- note that rows with partition IDs 1 and 2 are both slotted into partition 2:

```
df_naive_repartition = df.repartition(n_partitions, "partition_id").withColumn("actual_partition_id", F.spark_partition_id())
df_naive_repartition.orderBy("partition_id", "val").show()

#+------------+---+-------------------+
#|partition_id|val|actual_partition_id|
#+------------+---+-------------------+
#|           1| A0|                  2|
#|           1| A1|                  2|
#|           2| B0|                  2|
#|           2| B1|                  2|
#|           3| C0|                  0|
#|           3| C1|                  0|
#+------------+---+-------------------+
```

Whereas adding the deterministic partition key and then repartitioning by it results in each group being assigned to exactly one partition:

```
df = add_deterministic_1to1_partitioner(df, "partition_id", "deterministic_partition_id", partition_levels)
df_1to1_repartition = df.repartition(n_partitions, "deterministic_partition_id").withColumn("actual_partition_id", F.spark_partition_id())
df_1to1_repartition.orderBy("partition_id", "val").show()

#+------------+---+--------------------------+-------------------+
#|partition_id|val|deterministic_partition_id|actual_partition_id|
#+------------+---+--------------------------+-------------------+
#|           1| A0|                        28|                  0|
#|           1| A1|                        28|                  0|
#|           2| B0|                        29|                  1|
#|           2| B1|                        29|                  1|
#|           3| C0|                        27|                  2|
#|           3| C1|                        27|                  2|
#+------------+---+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

(The `deterministic_partition_id` column can be dropped after the repartitioning -- I show it here only to add a little clarity about how the hash map function works.)

Answer (score 15):

There is no such option with Python and `DataFrame` API. Partitioning API in `Dataset` is not plugable and supports only predefined [range and hash partitioning schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30995699/8371915).

You can convert data to `RDD`, partition with custom partitioner, and read convert back to `DataFrame`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct, spark_partition_id

mapping = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(
    df.select("partition_id").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
)}

result = (df
    .select("partition_id", struct([c for c in df.columns]))
    .rdd.partitionBy(len(mapping), lambda k: mapping[k])
    .values()
    .toDF(df.schema))

result.withColumn("actual_partition_id", spark_partition_id()).show()
# +------------+---+-------------------+
# |partition_id|val|actual_partition_id|
# +------------+---+-------------------+
# |           1|  A|                  0|
# |           1|  B|                  0|
# |           2|  A|                  1|
# |           2|  C|                  1|
# +------------+---+-------------------+
```

Please remember that this only creates specific distribution of data and doesn't set partitioner that can be used by Catalyst optimizer.

Comment: Doesn't `repartition` with a column run something like `hashcode(key) % numPartitions`? if so, shouldn't it return a seperate partition for each unique key?

Comment: @philantrovert Indeed, but OP seems to want 1:1 relationship, which [is not guaranteed with hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424396/8371915).

Comment: I dont understand why the .select() includes struct([c for c in df.columns]) separate from the partition_id.  Partition_id is one of df.columns, doesn't this select it twice?  Also, i'm on spark 2.2, is this answer still current?

Comment: @justincress: indeed, after the second the `partition_id` column is included twice -- once as a column on its own, once as an element of the struct column. `partitionBy` interprets each `Row` as a key-value mapping, with the first column the key and the remaining columns the value. Taking `.values()` then drops the key column (in this case `partition_id`), which is now extraneous. The solution works on Spark 2.2+.