# Is it possible to coalesce Spark partitions "evenly"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

Suppose we have a PySpark dataframe with data spread evenly across 2048 partitions, and we want to coalesce to 32 partitions to write the data back to HDFS. Using `coalesce` is nice for this because it does not require an expensive shuffle.

But one of the downsides of `coalesce` is that it typically results in an uneven distribution of data across the new partitions. I assume that this is because the original partition IDs are hashed to the new partition ID space, and the number of collisions is random.

However, in principle it should be possible to coalesce evenly, so that the first 64 partitions from the original dataframe are sent to the first partition of the new dataframe, the next 64 are send to the second partition, and so end, resulting in an even distribution of partitions. The resulting dataframe would often be more suitable for further computations.

Is this possible, while preventing a shuffle?

I can force the relationship I would like between initial and final partitions using a trick like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757050/how-to-force-a-certain-partitioning-in-a-pyspark-dataframe), but Spark doesn't know that everything from each original partition is going to a particular new partition. Thus it can't optimize away the shuffle, and it runs much slower than `coalesce`.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer and sorry for the misunderstanding. Why do you assume that coalescing will spread the data unevenly? If the current number of partitions is a multiple of the desired one, I would expect each new partition to have an even number of upstream partitions in the lineage of the coalesced one. Does this make sense for you? I'll check in the code anyhow.

Comment: Checked and added a new answer, you're safe to coalesce and be safe about not going to shuffle while retaining the even-ness. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can safely coalesce the 2048 partitions into 32 and assume that Spark is going to evenly assign the upstream partitions to the coalesced ones (64 for each in your case).

Here is [an extract from the Scaladoc of `RDD#coalesce`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L427-L430):

> This results in a narrow dependency, e.g. if you go from 1000 partitions to 100 partitions, there will not be a shuffle, instead each of the 100 new partitions will claim 10 of the current partitions.

Consider that also how your partitions are physically spread across the cluster influence the way in which coalescing happens. The following is an extract from [CoalescedRDD's ScalaDoc](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/CoalescedRDD.scala#L135-L142):

> If there is no locality information (no preferredLocations) in the parent, then the coalescing is very simple: chunk parents that are close in the Array in chunks.
>   If there is locality information, it proceeds to pack them with the following four goals:
>
> (1) Balance the groups so they roughly have the same number of parent partitions
>
> (2) Achieve locality per partition, i.e. find one machine which most parent partitions prefer
>
> (3) Be efficient, i.e. O(n) algorithm for n parent partitions (problem is likely NP-hard)
>
> (4) Balance preferred machines, i.e. avoid as much as possible picking the same preferred machine

Comment: Unfortunately, I can see empirically that my data starts with a nice even distribution across partitions, and ends with a uneven distribution. The numbers are slightly different than in the post, but the original dataframe has 768 partitions, with 294k records per partition on average and very small variance. Final dataframe after coalesce has 48 partitions -- some of these partitions have data from as few as 13 of the original partitions and others from as many as 19, with corresponding variation in number of records.

Comment: If it matters, I'm using PySpark, and my sparkContext.version reports 2.2.0.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, the documented behavior is different. I would open a ticket for this. Also, how are partitions spread across the cluster? Perhaps coalescing also takes into account about the physical location of partitions and tries to optimize for that.

Comment: I edited my answer: seems like my intuition could point you in the right direction. Check how partitions are spread in different machines, locality information may influence how new partitions are deriving from the old ones.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer, but it's unclear how I can go about digging further because I don't know how to find the preferred locations for my partitions. I asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872579/how-to-determine-preferred-location-for-partitions-of-pyspark-dataframe.

Comment: The preferred partitions are there to improve locality. I would not recommend trying to go low level, otherwise having a framework starts having less sense. The idea is that data is already partitioned in an optimal way for you, if you want to intervene on that the right thing to do would be to write your own PartitionCoalescer, but that would mean going to Scala.

Comment: I dug deeper, and apparently my partitions do not have preferred locations. So we're left with explanations #3 and #4. At this point I am happy to give up. :)