# How to determine "preferred location" for partitions of PySpark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I'm trying to understand how `coalesce` determines how to join initial partitions into final questions, and apparently the "preferred location" has something to do with it.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799726/how-to-set-preferred-locations-for-rdd-partitions-manually), Scala Spark has a function `preferredLocations(split: Partition)` that can identify this. But I'm not at all familiar with the Scala side of Spark. Is there a way to determine the preferred location of a given row or partition ID at the PySpark level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is theoretically possible. Example data to force some form of preference (there could be a simpler example):

```py
rdd1 = sc.range(10).map(lambda x: (x % 4, None)).partitionBy(8)
rdd2 = sc.range(10).map(lambda x: (x % 4, None)).partitionBy(8)

# Force caching so downstream plan has preferences
rdd1.cache().count()

rdd3 = rdd1.union(rdd2)
```

Now you can define a helper:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext

def prefered_locations(rdd):
    def to_py_generator(xs):
        """Convert Scala List to Python generator"""
        j_iter = xs.iterator()
        while j_iter.hasNext():
            yield j_iter.next()

    # Get JVM
    jvm =  SparkContext._active_spark_context._jvm
    # Get Scala RDD
    srdd = jvm.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.toRDD(rdd._jrdd)
    # Get partitions
    partitions = srdd.partitions()
    return {
        p.index(): list(to_py_generator(srdd.preferredLocations(p)))
        for p in partitions
    }
```

Applied:

```py
prefered_locations(rdd3)

# {0: ['...'],
#  1: ['...'],
#  2: ['...'],
#  3: ['...'],
#  4: [],
#  5: [],
#  6: [],
#  7: []}
```

Comment: This code runs without errors on my RDD and returns the expected number of partitions, but all have an empty list. Can I take this to mean that my partitions don't actually have any preferred location information? Or could this be a bug?

Comment: Many RDDs won't have preferred locations at all (that's why this quite elaborate example). Even in the above example only some partitions (I believe this is a result of partitioner aware union) have preferred locations. If you use sources which support data locality constraints it should more obvious.