# Spark DataFrame partitioner is None

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[New to Spark]
After creating a DataFrame I am trying to partition it based on a column in the DataFrame. When I check the partitioner using `data_frame.rdd.partitioner` I get *None* as output.

Partitioning using ->

```
data_frame.repartition("column_name")
```

As per Spark documentation the default partitioner is HashPartitioner, how can I confirm that ?

Also, how can I change the partitioner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's to be expected. `RDD` converted from a `Dataset` [doesn't preserve the partitioner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32920122/10465355), only the data distribution.

If you want to inspect partitioner of the RDD you should retrieve it from the `queryExecution`:

```
scala> val df = spark.range(100).select($"id" % 3 as "id").repartition(42, $"id")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: bigint]

scala> df.queryExecution.toRdd.partitioner
res1: Option[org.apache.spark.Partitioner] = Some(org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CoalescedPartitioner@4be2340e)
```

> how can I change the partitioner ?

In general you cannot. There exist `repartitionByRange` method (see the linked thread), but otherwise `Dataset` `Partitioner` is not configurable.