# Apache Spark: explode results in shuffle spill

Tags: apache-spark

I have 40GB of csv files. After reading them, I need to perform a series of transformations. One of them is to explode a column. After that transformation I get the shuffle spill depicted below. I understand why that is the case. The explosion is based on a broadcast variable lookup which gives a very skewed set of results.

My question is - how can I mitigate the spill? I tried repartitioning before the `explode` function by tuning the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` configuration parameter in order to ensure that the shuffle partitions are of equal size but that didn't help.

Any suggestions or literature on the topic would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Spill]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with RDDs you can use the built-in partitioners of Spark to customise the distribution of your data accross partitions. You can choose between a HashPartitioner and a RangePartitioner. Both work for discrete values and continuous values.

Example HashPartitioner:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

val rdd = df.rdd // convert DataFrame to low-level RDD
val keyedRDD = rdd.keyBy(...) // define your custom key
keyedRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(n))
```

Example Partitioner:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner

class DomainParitioner extends Partitioner {
  def numPartitions = n
  def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
    // your custome partition logic
  }
}

keyedRDD.partitionBy(new DomainPartitioner).map(_._1).glom().map(_.toSet.toSeq.length)
```

Comment: Thanks @mike! I was successful with my computation even though I still get several TBs of memory spill.
For the others reading this - it is not so straight forward to implement your own custom partitioner if you are coming from a DF. This answer (the pre Spark 1.6) helped me get it right - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32920122/1450817