# How to partition RDD by key in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Given that the HashPartitioner docs say:

> [HashPartitioner] implements hash-based partitioning using Java's
>   Object.hashCode.

Say I want to partition `DeviceData` by its `kind`.

```
case class DeviceData(kind: String, time: Long, data: String)
```

Would it be correct to partition an `RDD[DeviceData]` by overwriting the `deviceData.hashCode()` method and use only the hashcode of `kind`?

But given that `HashPartitioner` takes a number of partitions parameter I am confused as to whether I need to know the number of kinds in advance and what happens if there are more kinds than partitions?

Is it correct that if I write partitioned data to disk it will stay partitioned when read?

My goal is to call

```
  deviceDataRdd.foreachPartition(d: Iterator[DeviceData] => ...)
```

And have only `DeviceData`'s of the same `kind` value in the iterator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about just doing a `groupByKey` using `kind`. Or another `PairRDDFunctions` method.

You make it seem to me that you don't really care about the partitioning, just that you get all of a specific kind in one processing flow?

The pair functions allow this:

```
rdd.keyBy(_.kind).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(PARTITIONS))
   .foreachPartition(...)
```

However, you can probably be a little safer with something more like:

```
rdd.keyBy(_.kind).reduceByKey(....)
```

or `mapValues` or a number of the other pair functions that guarantee you get the pieces as a whole

Answer (score 9):

> Would it be correct to partition an RDD[DeviceData] by overwriting the deviceData.hashCode() method and use only the hashcode of kind?

It wouldn't be. If you take at the Java `Object.hashCode` documentation you'll find following information about the general contract of `hashCode`:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

So unless notion of equality based purely on a `kind` of device fits your use case, and I seriously doubt it does, tinkering with `HashCode` to get desired partitioning is a bad idea. In general case you should [implement your own partitioner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228151/1560062) but here it is not required.

Since, excluding specialized scenarios in SQL and GraphX, `partitionBy` is valid only on `PairRDD` it makes sense to create `RDD[(String, DeviceData)]` and use plain `HashPartitioner`

```
deviceDataRdd.map(dev => (dev.kind, dev)).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(n))
```

Just keep in mind that in a situation where `kind` has low cardinality or highly skewed distribution using it for partitioning may be not an optimal solution.

Comment: Good point. The objects should not be equal bc they have the same kind.

Comment: No. There is a logical fallacy here ->"unless notion of equality based purely on a kind of device fits your use case, and I seriously doubt it does, tinkering with HashCode to get desired partitioning is a bad idea"

HashCode based on Kind doesnt imply that Equality is based purely on Kind. Just that, *if* 2 records are Equal, they have same Kind, and thats easily satisfied.