# Spark dataset custom partitioner

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

*Could you please help me to find Java API for repartitioning `sales` dataset to `N` patitions of equal-size?* By equal-size I mean equal number of rows.

```
Dataset<Row> sales = sparkSession.read().parquet(salesPath);
sales.toJavaRDD().partitions().size(); // returns 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Define Custom partitioner for Spark RDDs of equally sized partition where each partition has equal number of elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127329/how-to-define-custom-partitioner-for-spark-rdds-of-equally-sized-partition-where)

Comment: @BradleyKaiser no, I am sure that answer is bad because of two reasons: 1) the answer show code of partitioner, but do not point how to pass custom partitioner to RDD API, that actually a question 2) the partitioner code is in Scala, Scala API may differ from Java API

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK custom partitioners are not supported for Datasets. The whole idea of Dataset and Dataframe APIs in Spark 2+ is to abstract away the need to meddle with custom partitioners. And so if we face the need to deal with Data-skew and come to a point where custom partitioner is the only option, I guess we would go to lower level RDD manipulation.

For eg: [Facebook use-case-study](https://code.facebook.com/posts/678403995666478/using-apache-spark-for-large-scale-language-model-training/) and [Spark summit talk related to the use-case-study](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur_wLGE1aGA&feature=youtu.be)

For defining partitioners for RDDs, it is well documented in the [API doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)