# Spark repartition does not distribute records evenly

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, rdd

I have an rdd which I re-partition by one field

```
   rdd = rdd.repartition( new Column("block_id"));
```

and save it to hdfs.

I would expect that if there are 20 different `block_id`'s, the repartitioning would produce 20 new partitions each holding a different `block_id`.
But in fact after repartitioning there are 19 partitions, each holding exactly one `block_id` and one partition holding two `block_id`'s.
This means that the core writing the partition with the two `block_id`'s to disk takes twice the time compared to the other cores and therefore doubling the overall time.

Comment: I'm confused, the method `repartition` on `RDD` only takes an `Int`, not a `Column`

Answer (score 1):

Spark `Dataset` uses hash partitioning. There is no guarantee that there will be no [hash colisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) so you cannot expect:

> that if there are 20 different block_id's, the repartitioning would produce 20 new partitions each holding a different block_id

You can try to increase number of partitions but it using number which offers good guarantees is rather impractical.

With RDDs you can design your own partitioner [How to Define Custom partitioner for Spark RDDs of equally sized partition where each partition has equal number of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23127329/8371915)